# What is motivation behind understanding many body localization?

Tags: many-body, anderson-localization

I'm reading about many body localization which consider both interaction and disorder. But I don't know why this topic has gained so much attention? What is harder part of this localization that makes it more interesting. If I compare it with Anderson localization I can argue that MBL considers the interaction b/w particles but what does it tell us what happens when we switch on interaction?Does the state remain confine? If there is interaction b/w particles there must be energy emission. Where this energy is utilized?

Comment: You seem to have quite a number of questions about localization and the various models. Many of them seem fairly elementary. I might suggest that you take the time to really dig into the theories to understand what they are doing. Ultimately that is the only way to really understand it. Then you can ask more focused questions here to pull out details.